# Android usb host communication

Tags: android, usb, communication

I need my hardware to communicate via usb, acting as an usb host. Is there a way of doing this, if I'm using android 2.3.3? As I researched, there's support for doing this from android api 3.1 and higher.

Comment: You want your Android device to act as USB host, or you have some other hardware device you want to be the host?

Comment: The android device will act as an USB host

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find a custom android 2.3.3 ROM that has USB drivers that support this.

Even if you did this, your phone would only be able to use Apps for 2.3.3 and lower, which do not have the USB Host hardware code from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html). So unless you put a [ubuntu distro on the phone or something](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/) you won't be able to do much with the USB peripherals.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not,...

Android USB hosting was introduced on the Motorola Xoom (3.1).  Not all devices have this functionality.

What you need is the USB Accessory Kit (but this works in 2.3.4)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html